# Sql 2 inner joins other data outcome

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

Can someone explain the following.

```
SELECT results.`referentie`,products.`categorie`,products.`url`,products.`inkoopPrijs`,SUM(results.`stockverschil`) AS 'stockverschil'
    FROM `results` results
    INNER JOIN products
    ON products.`referentie` = results.`referentie` 
    WHERE results.`datum` BETWEEN '2017-01-11' AND '2017-01-12' AND results.`referentie`= '1'
```

The result is a `stockverschil` outcome of 200. (the right amount)

```
SELECT results.`referentie`,products.`categorie`,products.`url`,products.`inkoopPrijs`,sold.`winstPerProductPerDag`,SUM(results.`stockverschil`) AS 'stockverschil'
    FROM `results` results
    INNER JOIN products
    ON products.`referentie` = results.`referentie` 
    INNER JOIN sold
    ON sold.`referentie` = results.`referentie`
    WHERE results.`datum` BETWEEN '2017-01-11' AND '2017-01-12' AND results.`referentie`= '1'
```

The result is a `stockverschil` outcome of 4800.
Am i doing something wrong with the INNER JOIN?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: What does this mean:  "stockverschil outcome of 200"?

Comment: I'm using a Mysql database

Comment: One of the fields in my database, In dutch it stands for 'stock difference'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue on `sold`, being a one[product] to many[sold] relationship

Try this, with the appropriate aggregate function for`SUM(sold.winstPerProductPerDag)`

```
SELECT results.`referentie`,products.`categorie`,products.`url`,products.`inkoopPrijs`,s.`winstPerProductPerDag`,SUM(results.`stockverschil`) AS 'stockverschil'
FROM `results` results
INNER JOIN products
ON products.`referentie` = results.`referentie` 
INNER JOIN ( select SUM(sold.`winstPerProductPerDag`) as `winstPerProductPerDag`, sold.`referentie` from sold group by sold.`referentie`) s on s.`referentie` = results.`referentie`
WHERE results.`datum` BETWEEN '2017-01-11' AND '2017-01-12' AND results.`referentie`= '1'
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks!